# Why specify function return types?

Tags: typescript

Most of the time I read that we should use type inference as much as possible. When writing a function I understand we must type arguments since they cannot be inferred, but why do we have to type the return value? TypeScript is taking care of that. What are the benefits of explicitly typing the return value of a function? So far I only read that I should do it, but no one is saying why.

Comment: The benefit is the compiler can double-check your intent. Sure it'll infer the return type based on the implementation, but it might not be what you think the function should return (a common case: you miss a branch on a conditional and the function returns `T | undefined` instead of `T` - the compiler will happily infer the conditional type, but if you tell it you intended to always return a value it can tell you there's an issue in the implementation).

Comment: @jonrsharpe unless there is a good duplicate question/answer - your comment deserves to be posted (even as-is). I'd upvote :-)

Comment: @zerkms I feel like there must be, so I'm trying to find it! I'll post an answer if I can't.

Comment: A personal preference rule of thumb: explicit types for anything public, private stuff can rely on inference. This is entirely opinionated, of course.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The compiler can infer what your code *does*, but it has no idea what you *intended*. Take this trivial example:

```
function thing(value: string) {
    return value === "foo" ? 123 : "456";
}
```

The inferred type is `function thing(value: string): 123 | "456"`, and that matches the implementation, but is that in any meaningful sense *right*? Perhaps I intended to always return a `number`, for example; if I tell the compiler that, it can tell me I didn't:

```
Type 'string | number' is not assignable to type 'number'.
  Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'number'.(2322)
```

Particularly when you're using complex wrapper/generic types (e.g. I see issues around this a lot in [angular](/questions/tagged/angular) where RxJS observables are being used), this can really help getting early feedback on your assumptions.

---

I also work a lot with test-driven development (TDD), where one of the values of writing tests before implementation is that it gives you the opportunity to discuss the interface at a time where the cost of changing it is close to zero. Using the classic RPS example:

```
function rps(left: string, right: string) {
  return "right";
}

it("returns 'right' for 'rock' vs. 'paper'", () => {
  expect(rps("rock", "paper")).to.equal("right");
});
```

That'll compile and pass, but is it what we *want*? Now we can talk about options:

- Do we accept the inferred type `function rps(left: string, right: string): string`?
- Go more specific with e.g.

  ```
  type Throw = "rock" | "paper" | "scissors";
  type Outcome = "left" | "right" | "draw";
  function rps(left: Throw, right: Throw): Outcome { ... }
  ```
- Use [enums](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/enums.html) instead?

We can talk through the trade-offs and pick the best option given what we know at the time. The explicit return type serves as *documentation* of the decision we made.

---

I'd recommend making [`@typescript-eslint/explicit-function-return-type`](https://github.com/typescript-eslint/typescript-eslint/blob/master/packages/eslint-plugin/docs/rules/explicit-function-return-type.md) an error, if you're linting your code, which provides as its rationale:

> Explicit types for function return values makes it clear to any
> calling code what type is returned. This ensures that the return value
> is assigned to a variable of the correct type; or in the case where
> there is no return value, that the calling code doesn't try to use the
> undefined value when it shouldn't.

Comment: We have @typescript-eslint/explicit-function-return-type enabled with warn in my current project. It seems to just get ignored. So I think it needs more consideration than just enabling it to change the practice. A good explanation for the team, like the one you provided, should go a long way.

Comment: @MadsHoel enabling at warn is part of the problem - I'd advocate having _no_ warnings, either you care (and it's an error) or you don't (and it's off). Otherwise you just get an ever-longer list of maybe-fix-this and folks learn to ignore it.

Answer (score 9):

Here is one good reason to use explicit return types. According to [TS wiki](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/Performance#using-type-annotations):

> Adding type annotations, especially return types, can save the compiler a lot of work. In part, this is because named types tend to be more compact than anonymous types (which the compiler might infer), which reduces the amount of time spent reading and writing declaration files (e.g. for incremental builds). Type inference is very convenient, so there's no need to do this universally - however, it can be a useful thing to try if you've identified a slow section of your code.

Hence, if you don't have any problems with compliation performance I think it is not required to specify return types

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69551641/improve-typescript-speed-when-a-type-is-any-member-of-a-map/69576685#69576685) you can find another question/answer regarding compilation performance. It also relates to TypeScript [Performance wiki](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/Performance)

P.S. you can use explicit return type for disallowing using some extra properties of return value. Consider this exmaple:

```js
const foo = (): { age: number } => {
    const result = {
        age: 42,
        name: 'John'
    }
    return result
}

const result = foo()
result.age // ok
result.name //error
```

As you might have noticed, explicit `{age:number}` return type is a super type of a return value type. But it is weak, because it does not work if you want to return literal object, like here:

```js
const foo = (): { age: number } => ({
    age: 42,
    name: 'John' // error
})
```

So I can't recommend using this technique, however it worth knowing.

Comment: You have a nice blog! (no rss though :-( )

Comment: @zerkms thank you very much. It motivates! I will take lack of RSS into account.

Comment: Agreed except for the "only one good reason to use explicit return types" part. The other answer stated the other good reason and the reason I use it often.

Comment: @jperl you are right, I guess it worth removing this

Comment: I don't know what you mean by _"it is weak"_ - that object is _only_ accessible via the `{ age: number }` interface, so having a `name` prop is clearly redundant. In the former case `result` could be used via the `{ age: number; name: string }` interface _within_ the function.

Comment: @jonrsharpe I meant, if you want to disallow using some properties from return type, you can't rely only on providing explicit return type with less number of properties because it does not alway work

Comment: But it _only_ "doesn't work" in cases where you hit excess property checks, i.e. only when you immediately return an object that is inaccessible via any interface other than the return type. In those cases any other props are unusable, so trying to include them suggests the author is unclear about what's actually happening.

Comment: These are all great answers i wish i could accept multiple

Comment: @jonrsharpe just like I said, it worth knowing , it is related to using of explicit return type but I don't recommend it to use. This is only my opinion  which might be different from yours. We all have different experience and different style of coding.

Comment: I have no problem with your opinion, but if you're telling people they should know something you should endeavour to actually explain it. Why doesn't it work in that case? Why don't you recommend it? If it's worth knowing, that implies there are situations where you think it _should_ be used - how does one determine they're in such a situation? Etc.

Comment: @jonrsharpe you are right, thank you for your feedback, I will take it into consideration. Sorry, I did not have much time to extend my answer. Just wanted to provide small example from my experience, I thought it may help. If somebody is curious why it does not work in that case they always can ping me under the answer or ask new question on stackoverflow. Like I said, I don't have such experience as you on stackoverflow and my answers sometimes probably are not complete, still I'm trying to do my best. If you think my answer is not good enough - feel free to downvote it.

Comment: @zerkms btw, I have added RSS to my blog, see [here](https://catchts.com/subscribe)

Answer (score 6):

The main reason to annotate the return type of a function is the same as the main reason to use Typescript at all: because you want the compiler to check your code and give you useful error messages when you make certain kinds of mistakes.

If you let Typescript infer the return type of your function, then whatever it infers *will be* the return type of the function, even if the inferred type is not the type you intended. In this case, if you try to return something of the wrong type, the compiler will use that wrong type as the function's return type and you will get an error when you try to call the function and expect something of the right type - or worse, you won't get an error, but your code will fail at runtime or do the wrong thing.

On the other hand, if you know what you want the return type to be, and you want the compiler to check that your function actually does return something of that type, then you should use a type annotation. In this case, if you try to return something of the wrong type, then you'll get an error in the function itself, where the mistake actually was.