# TypeScript allowing incorrect properties via object destructuring

Tags: typescript

I'm running into an issue with TypeScript whereby an object using one type can be injected via a destructing assignment into an another object that uses a completely different type, and TypeScript doesn't show any errors for it.

An example being:

```js
interface Pizza {
    cookingTime: number;
    size: "Small" | "Medium" | "Large";
}

interface Car {
    modelName: string;
    yearManufactured: number;
}

const produceMalformedPizza = (car: Car): Pizza => {
    return {
        ...car, // This is not a "Pizza" object but no errors are raised
        cookingTime: 10,
        size: "Small",
    }
}

console.log(
    produceMalformedPizza({
        modelName: "NotAPizza",
        yearManufactured: 1980
    })
)

/* Output:
[LOG]: {
  "modelName": "NotAPizza",
  "yearManufactured": 1980,
  "cookingTime": 10,
  "size": "Small"
} 
*/
```

I've tried to turn every possible strict flag on — and you can see it compiling [online here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=99&ts=4.5.2&noUncheckedIndexedAccess=true&noUnusedLocals=true&noUnusedParameters=true&module=100&noFallthroughCasesInSwitch=true&useUnknownInCatchVariables=true&exactOptionalPropertyTypes=true&noImplicitOverride=true&noPropertyAccessFromIndexSignature=true#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgArAF4bsg3gKGSOQQHtSBrUAcwBVgBbCALmRAFcGAjaAbkOIBnTC2QAiAMoM4AGxljkAH3EBZCABNgnBcrEAZOFGoQx-AL758oSLEQoAwobwCiDUuogyAcnCatBYFA0-MTIAJ4QhipwHPAIYOxQGqwc3Hz4FvhkIAHIAA5Q7uxI0TIwpFBM6uhYOAC8yAAUCIasjlAAlKw12Mh1AHzOoUkJUCBDocQAdDMtUAA0LpNklDT0fsgAjAAMi5NCIqyS0nJie8QWmdmCpDIQUzKk1I1LBUUlsuWVGj1wjQT7VzuTw%20DZiLykMAAQV%20ZyWoQiURi7Dio2SWwAnAAObZLMwdfAdIA).

If I try to return any specific properties in the `produceMalformedPizza` function, then the compiler raises errors, as expected — but it seems as though I can inject arbitrary object data using a destructuring (spread) assignment.

I'm relatively new to TypeScript, so perhaps this is expected behaviour? I.e. I can't use object spread destructuring with inferred type safety?

**Edit:**

As per the answer from @T.J.Crowder this is intentional.

- There is some GitHub discussion about this *issue* specifically here: https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/43499,
- And also a proposal to support "Exact" types here: https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/12936

Comment: Related answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70001511/why-specify-function-return-types/70001674#70001674 .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's expected behavior. The object you're returning is a *subtype* of `Pizza` — it has all the properties `Pizza` requires (plus some that it doesn't).

TypeScript does do "excess property checks" but only in limited situations. For instance, if you were to put a non-`Pizza` property explicitly in that object literal, TypeScript would flag that up not because it's actually wrong from a type perspective (it's fine to use a subtype) but because it's *probably* a programmer mistake.

I'm slightly surprised it doesn't do that with `...car` (since `car` has required properties), but it doesn't do excess property checks in all situations.

Comment: It looks like destructuring `...car` is not treated as literal object, hence `excess property checks` are not applied. AFAIK, it is safe behavior

Comment: @captain-yossarian - Yup, but it would make sense to me for the same "pragmatic" excess property check to apply to spread properties as explicit properties. But perhaps it's too costly in terms of implementation/runtime.

Comment: I think this is because of mutable nature of js objects. Good news, you can't use `...car` at the end :)

Comment: @captain-yossarian - I'm afraid I don't understand. `car` has a definite type, with required properties that aren't part of `Pizza`, so including `...car` in the literal isn't fundamentally different from including `someNonPizzaProperty: "x"` in it. (Not sure what you mean about `...car` at the end, `return { cookingTime: 10, size: "Small", ...car }` also raises no flags.)

Comment: Sorry, I told you about using `car` at the end, I was wrong, it does not trigger an errors. My example was completely changed, that's why I got an error

Comment: Thanks for your answer, @T.J.Crowder — definitely makes more sense now you've pointed out that it's technically a subtype. But, it's a somewhat worrying find because this seems to imply that we can't safely use spread syntax on objects?

Comment: @Sarreph - You can, it's just you have to be aware of the types involved when you do. I'm surprised by it. You might look at the TypeScript issue list, maybe they consider it a bug (since the equivalent without spread would get caught by excess property checks).